# Incomplete Definition of Type

Tags: c

Any advice on this?
Based on other examples, most are done this way. I'm unsure why is this giving me an error.

Is it because I have to call it first somewhere ?

```
typedef struct tldnode TLDNode;
char *tldnode_tldname(TLDNode *node);
long tldnode_count(TLDNode *node);


struct TLDNode
{
    char* key;
    long nodeCount;
};

char *tldnode_tldname(TLDNode *node){
     return node->key;
}

long tldnode_count(TLDNode *node){
    return node->nodeCount;
}
```

[image]

Comment: You may have been looking at examples in a different language, like C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`typedef struct tldnode TLDNode;`

is defining `TLDNode` to be a short cut for `struct tldnode`.

You never defined `struct tldnode` anywhere.

Down below, you define

```
struct TLDNode
{
    char* key;
    long nodeCount;
};
```

which is not `struct tldnode`

You want something like

```
typedef struct TLDNode___
{
    char* key;
    long nodeCount;
} TLDNode;
```

to both define the structure and give the shortcut name to the type.

EDIT:  based on your comments in the other answer, the quick and easy answer you're looking for is:

change

```
struct TLDNode
{
    char* key;
    long nodeCount;
};
```

to

```
struct tldnode
{
    char* key;
    long nodeCount;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to write `void someFunc(struct TLDNode *);` with *`struct`* since there's no type `TLDNode`, but `struct TLDNode` exists.

If you still want to use just `TLDNode`, then use a *typedef*:

```
typedef struct
{
    char* key;
    long nodeCount;
}TLDNode;
```

---

**Update**:

Regarding your last updates, you can first of all declare

```
typedef struct {
    char* key;
    long nodeCount;
}tldnode;
```

And only then you do `typedef tldnode TLDNode`.

Comment: My bad, i updated my question. Yeah I already have typedef i believe but still having the error

Comment: Still, your typedef won't compile as there's no type `tdlnode`. Try to replace your typedef and struct declaration with typedef in my answer.

Comment: Getting typedef redefinition with different types('struct TLDNode'vs 'struct tldnode')

Comment: @FlyingAtom, wait, are `tldnode` and `TLDNode` different types?

Comment: @FlyingAtom, you don't need any name when you're _typedef_'ing (nice verb, isn't it?). You can do `typedef struct {int a;}Name;` and that's all.

Comment: this is homework actually, i cant edit this typedef struct tldnode TLDNode; but tldnode on this line is giving me a warning saying unable to resolve forward declaration tldnode

Comment: your structure definition needs to use the first name used (`tldnode`) in the typdef, not the second (`TLDNode`)

Comment: @RussSchultz I see my mistake, I used the wrong one, i should had used tldnode instead of TLDNode. THanks!

Comment: @FlyingAtom, okay, `typedef tldnode TLDNode;` means there already is a type called `tldnode`, so you need to create one. Please see edits in my answer.